# how to turn a long set of numbers into formatted hours

Tags: javascript, google-visualization, number-formatting

I need to format a long set of numbers into hours.
You can see under the column time spent there is long numbers and these are hours they need to be formatted to not look like it does now,6,000, needs to look like 6,000hrs.

I have one other request I was able to format the Amount spent column however I do not know how to format the hAxis portion to show the dollar sign.

I am new to Google Charts, it's a fast learner. It just seems the documentation is spread out.

```
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawTimeAndAmountSpentTimeLineChart);
    //Amount Completed
    function drawTimeAndAmountSpentTimeLineChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
            ['Web Design', 'Amount Spent', 'Time Spent'],
            ['Rendering Engines', 5000, 68000],
            ['User Management', 9000, 44000],
            ['Database', 5700, 32000],
            ['Security', 9000, 21000]
        ]);

        var options = {
            title: 'Amount Spent Per Task',
            chartArea: { width: '70%' },
            hAxis: {
                title: 'Total Spent',
                minValue: 0,
                prefix: '$'
            },
            vAxis: {
                title: 'Task'
            }
        };

        var formatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({ prefix: '$' });
        formatter.format(data, 1);


        var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('timeAndAmountSpentTimeLineChart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
    };
```

**If not asking for to much the bars the run horizontal need to be about 50px in height and not the tiny height. that would be a great help.**

I have not idea why it is not drawing in js fiddle it is drawing in my machine.

[My Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/alumcloud/0e2817od/3/)

Comment: `I have not idea why it is not drawing in js fiddle` perhaps it's the **TypeError: google.visualization is undefined**

Comment: I am new to Fiddle as well; however, I add the two external JS file so it should work.

Comment: you added jsapi and loader - but that doesn't seem to load `visualization` code ... are you sure you added everything as you need it?

Comment: was missing `load` statement, don't need `jsapi` -- [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0e2817od/5/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the `pattern` property of [NumberFormat](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#numberformat) for `'Time Spent'`

for the x-axis labels --> `hAxis.format`

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Web Design', 'Amount Spent', 'Time Spent'],
        ['Rendering Engines', 5000, 68000],
        ['User Management', 9000, 44000],
        ['Database', 5700, 32000],
        ['Security', 9000, 21000]
    ]);

    var options = {
        title: 'Amount Spent Per Task',
        chartArea: { width: '70%' },
        hAxis: {
            title: 'Total Spent',
            minValue: 0,
            format: '$#,##0'
        },
        vAxis: {
            title: 'Task'
        }
    };

    var formatAmt = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({ prefix: '$' });
    formatAmt.format(data, 1);

    var formatTime = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({ pattern: '#,##0 hrs' });
    formatTime.format(data, 2);

    var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('timeAndAmountSpentTimeLineChart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  },
  packages: ['corechart']
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="timeAndAmountSpentTimeLineChart_div"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much this is perfect!